# Permitted function types in Pandoc filters

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I have a complex html document that I've read into pandoc, and I'm trying to write filters that will isolate the content I'm after. Some examples of this are dropping certain Divs entirely, or replacing Tables by just the content of their rows.

I was [told on the pandoc mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/idlbnOk1ooE) that the existence of an instance `Walkable a b => Walkable a [b]` means you can also write functions of type `Block -> [Block]` and represnt the omitting of elements as `[]`. This works, but I don't understand why, which is my question:

The way I understood it, [the signature of walk](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.12/docs/Text-Pandoc-Walk.html) (which turns functions into filters), `(a -> a) -> b -> b`, meant that using a function of type `Block -> [Block]` would not compile, since that doesn't fit the `(a -> a)` bit of the signature. Also in my understanding, the existence of `instance Walkable a b => Walkable a [b]` just describes how `walk` behaves when confronted with a list instead of a single element to apply `f :: a -> a` to. I don't see how it's related to what happens when f is of type `a -> [a]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `f` is `Block -> [Block]`, as you notice, `walk f` won't type check. But `toJSONFilter f` will.  To see why, check out the source for `ToJSONFilter` in `Text.Pandoc.JSON`.  It contains the instance:

```
instance Data a => ToJSONFilter (a -> [a]) where
  toJSONFilter f = BL.getContents >>=
    BL.putStr . encode . (bottomUp (concatMap f) :: Pandoc -> Pandoc) .
    either error id . eitherDecode'
```

So we can apply `toJSONFilter` to a `Block -> [Block]` function.

How does it work? As you can see, `bottomUp` (which wraps a function from `syb`) is being used behind the scenes, instead of `walk`. `bottomUp` is defined in `Text.Pandoc.Generic` as

```
bottomUp :: (Data a, Data b) => (a -> a) -> b -> b
bottomUp f = everywhere (mkT f)
```

Since `Block` is an instance of `Data`, we can use `bottomUp` to promote a `[Block] -> [Block]` function to a `Pandoc -> Pandoc`.  `f` was `Block -> [Block]`, but `concatMap f` is `[Block] -> [Block]`, so we use that.

Hope that answers your question.  Note that because of the use of `syb` generics, this approach will not perform as well as one that uses `Walk`.  So there is some room for improvement in the pandoc API.

Comment: Thanks for your response; not only does this answer my question, but it clarifies a few other things for me as well :-)